# how to run a callback after real DOM update in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and interested in running a function after a component has rendered into the real DOM.

It seems that `componentDidUpdate()` happens after the `render()` hook but before the real DOM is actually updated. This is problematic because I am trying to run a processor intensive calculation after `render()` and it is causing the DOM update to delay.

For clarity sake here's what I am trying to achieve:

1. User Clicks the component.
2. A callback is fired which updates the state.
3. render() is fired because of update to state
4. The real dom is updated (in my case changing a style attribute)
5. Then only once the client has received the new style,  a function is fired which performs a calculation that takes some time to complete - say one to three seconds.
6. The calculation completes and the state is updated again.
7. New re-render
8. New real DOM update.

Is something like this possible in React?

Comment: What's the calculation? Could be delegated to a worker if possible. It's not a good idea to block main thread for several seconds any way.

Comment: In React generally you shouldn't be worrying too much about the real DOM - React abstracts that for you. Maybe provide some code samples so we can get a better idea of what you want.

If you have an action that takes some seconds to complete then make it asynchronous and provide a callback. Then, in the callback update the component state. That, in turn, will update your component's rendering.